# import a function from a saved file with numbers Python3x

Tags: python-3.x, function, import

I have a function in a file called `09_09.py`. I would like to call it from another file `file.py`. Both files are in the same folder/directory. I have tried it in `Pycharm` several times, but it always gives me an error.

What can I do with a program that is saved like that?

I'm sorry for my English. I am from Colombia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename of the source of the function, starts with a number. As such, the typical `import` will not work.

A good workaround, would be to use something like:

```
module_09_09 = __import__('09_09')
```

Later, to call your function you could do:

```
module_09_09.my_function_call()
```

Comment: @JulianDavidChiscoHenao You are welcome! If this helped, you, please consider "accepting" the answer from the left with the green checkmark button!